# Error "Amplify.AuthError error 2" thrown during the sign in flow on iOS with amplify-swift 1.15.1

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

During the sign in flow in iOS, for few users the `Authentication` module of the `amplify-swift` library throws the error `The operation couldn't be completed. (Amplify.AuthError error 2)`. I have searched in the `amplify-swift` repository for possible solutions but couldn't find any. The version of `Amplify` pod used in code is `1.15.1`.

```
func nativeLogin(
  email: String?, password: String?, completion: @escaping (Result<Authstate, Error>) -> Void
) {
  let isAlreadySignedIn = AWSMobileClient.default().isSignedIn
  if isAlreadySignedIn {
    // Do signout and then sign in
    let options = AuthSignOutRequest.Options(globalSignOut: true)
    Amplify.Auth.signOut(options: options) {
      result in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if case .success = result {
          // completion(.success(.logout))
          guard let email = email,
            let password = password
          else {
            self.response(
              completion, .failure(AuthError.passwordValidationError("Missing Email/Password")))
            return
          }
          // log event
          self.signIn(email: email, password: password, completion: completion)
        } else if case .failure(let error) = result {
          // log event
          completion(.failure(error))
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    self.signIn(email: email, password: password, completion: completion)
  }
}
```

The reason that the `signOut` method is invoked before actually signing in is to ensure that last logged in user is signed out first.

Can anyone explain where am I going wrong? Or has this error been already fixed in the latest version (`2.2.1`) of the `amplify-swift` library?

Comment: Did you try to use Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { result in } to get the isSignedIn status from Amplify end?

Comment: @chinthakad Are you  suggesting to not use `AWSMobileClient.default().isSignedIn` for checking the status and replace it with `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession`?